# elasticsearch plugins too slow

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am running an elasticsearch server on my vm server (windows 2008 server r2) with 2 plugins "head" and "kibana". When I try to access to this url "servername:9200" everything works well and fast, I am getting the response.

But when I am trying to access to theses urls "servername:9200/_plugin/head" or "servername:9200/_plugin/kibana", the browser page stay white with the loading symbole circle keeping turning. I don't knowh why, I have checked my server activity and there is no overload (cpu,memory,disk).